# Extracting component classes with @apply display background image still error

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

my code css

```
 @layer components {
        .hero-image {
            @apply bg-blue-700 background-image: url("/assets/images/hero-image.jpg");
        }
    }
```

if me put bg-blue-700 can be display but me put background-image got error " Syntax Error: Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element. "
at Array.forEach ()

please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to a different line.

```
.hero-image {
    @apply bg-blue-700;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/hero-image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Still error bro, me fix using vue style scope. <style scoped>
.hero-image {
  background-image: url("./assets/images/hero-image.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>

Comment: idk fix it, maybe me wrong config tailwind in vue.